# pasting and automatically replace paragraph spaces with line spaces

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I'm interested in saving time copy-pasting. I copy paste from websites, articles, newspapers, etc, which have different formatting. When I paste it into my word doc, it typically comes up messy because of paragraph space formatting. I'm wondering if there's a shortcut to replace paragraph spaces with line spaces. It sucks having to go to the end of each line in the copypasted text and hit delete to remove the paragraph spaces. Here's a visualization of what I'm talking about. "Pasted" is what appears when I paste something. "Desired Format" is what I want, by replacing paragraph breaks with line spaces.

Update: 
Oh right, yes, line break with a space. I am also pasting "text only", though I have tried "keep source formatting", and "merge formatting", all of which don't give me the results I want.

[image]

Comment: Okay, you mean replacing a line break with a space, right? "Paragraph break" is not a technical term, nor is "line space."

Comment: What paste function are you using; "Keep source formatting", "merge formatting" or "text only"?

Comment: Oh right, yes, line break with a space. I am also pasting "text only", though I have tried "keep source formatting", and "merge formatting", all of which don't give me the results I want.

Comment: Have you tried using the `Paste Special` function? If memory serves, it should allow you to specify a great deal about what formatting is kept. However, I suspect that the reason this may be happening is because the source actually has newline characters in-text; if that's the case, there's probably no simple way to do this in one step.

Comment: @CharlieRB Neither of them replace line breaks with spaces.